# Visual FoxPro with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, foxpro, visual-foxpro

Could someone please tell any resources or links to learn usage of Mercurial with Visual FoxPro 9.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ganapathy,

The white paper from my *VFP Version Control with Mercurial* session at Southwest Fox 2011 is now available for download as a PDF from the developers page of my website at http://www.ita-software.com/foxpage.aspx. The direct link to the paper is http://bit.ly/IgXzhM. This is introductory material intended as a jump start for VFP developers who have never used Mercurial, or perhaps not even any distributed version control system (DVCS). I hope you find it useful.

-Rick

Answer (score 2):

Rick Borup (http://www.ita-software.com/foxpage.aspx) presented a pre-conference session on this topic at Southwest Fox 2011. He wrote a terrific 59-page paper for it.

I don't know whether he has published that paper elsewhere.

Tamar

Comment: Yeah, I knew it and tried searching for that but couldn't get!

Comment: You can email Rick directly and ask whether he'll share it.

Comment: Rock usually makes his whitepapers available 6 months after the conference is open.

Comment: @MattSlay Thanks. It would be great if Rick could do that!